# TableColumn doesn't display values (JavaFX 11)

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tablecolumn

I made TableView with two columns - first assigned to a value from class from List imported from other TableView via selection model, second assigned to some value of the class. But second column still stays empty.

I'm setting up a TableView which contains Player's nickname (String) and his seat (int). I generated in main controll TableView which was generated from SQL table by Hibernate. Player's values imported from SQL table are annotaded by @Column, the value 'seat' has annotation @Transient. I tried to do this by methods found on stack but they're not working here.

Here is controller which contains the TableView:

```
public class SeatsController {
private ObservableList<Player> players;

@FXML private TableView<Player> playersTableSeats;
@FXML private TableColumn playerColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<Player, String> seatColumn;

@FXML private TextField seatField;

public void initialize() {
    players = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    playersTableSeats.setItems(players);
    seatColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getSeat()+"", "seat"));
}

public void manageSeats(List<Player> list) {
    players.addAll(list);
}

@FXML
public void setSeat() {
    Player selectedPlayer = 
playersTableSeats.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    selectedPlayer.setSeat(Integer.parseInt(seatField.getText()));
    playersTableSeats.setItems(players);
    System.out.println(selectedPlayer.getSeat());
}
}
```

Part of FXML file (seats.fxml):

```
<TableView fx:id="playersTableSeats">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="playerColumn" text="Nickname">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="nickname"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn fx:id="seatColumn" text="Seat">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="seat"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
<HBox>
    <Label text="Set place:"></Label>
    <TextField fx:id="seatField"></TextField>
    <Button text="OK" onAction="#setSeat"></Button>
</HBox>
```

Class player:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Players")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Player {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "nickname")
private String nickname;

@Column(name = "chips")
private int chips;

@Column(name = "notes")
private String notes;

@Transient
private int seat;

[some values with @Transient]

public Player() {}

public Player(int id, String nickname, int chips, String notes) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nickname = nickname;
    this.chips = chips;
    this.notes = notes;
    seat = -1;
}
}
```

Getters and setters are default (created by lombok but don't care).

Start of this controller is caused by:

```
SeatsController seatsController = fxmlLoader.getController();
seatsController.manageSeats(selectedPlayers);
```

in main Controller after correct selection and click on the button 'Run!'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/upned.png

I try to do something with seatColumn.setCellValueFactory([lambda]) and setCellValue([lambda]) but all of my attempts fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong `SimpleStringProperty` constructor for the intended purpose:

`SimpleStringProperty​(Object bean, String name)` only receives "metadata" about the property, but not doesn't actually initialize the value:

- `bean` is the object containing the property
- `name` is a string containing the name of the property

Both are used to assign the properties of the same name for the property object.

`TableView` doesn't do anything with those properties. It simply uses the value which is not assigned by the constructor used and therefore remains at the initial value of `null`.

You could use

```
seatColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(Integer.toString(cellData.getValue().getSeat())));
```

However I recommend keeping the type of the property instead of converting to `String`:

```
@FXML private TableColumn<Player, Number> seatColumn;
```

```
seatColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellData.getValue().getSeat()));
```

---

Initializing the `cellValueFactory` from the `initialize` method you should remove the creation of the factory from the fxml file, since just the factory assigned later is used by `TableView`.